# Right to left edge case

Tags: html, css

I have the following edge case that seems to get styled wrong when using `direction: rtl`

I have the following sentence in English:

Lorem Ipsum @username 1000 units

When displayed in Hebrew it reads:

לורם איפסום @username 1000 יחידות

Here in Stackoverflow it displays in the correct order since the website is in styled with the default LTR direction, when changing to RTL, the `@username` and the `1000` parts get mixed up, the order is incorrect.

Here's an example of how it looks:

```css
p {
  direction: rtl
}
```

```html
<p>לורם איפסום @username 1000 יחידות</p>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the problem markup here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the username in a span a give it a dir attribute along with an appropriate lang attribute.

```html
<p>לורם איפסום <span dir="ltr" lang="en">@username 1000</span> יחידות</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the `&lrm;` ([left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)) control character before the '@' character - to indicate that the '@' is actually English

2) Add the `&rlm;` ([Right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)) control character before the number 1000 to indicate that it is part of the Hebrew sentence.

```css
p {
  direction: rtl
}
```

```html
<p>לורם איפסום &lrm;@username &rlm;1000 יחידות</p>
```

NB: No extra tags are necessary!!

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/qjQRMw)